# Automatic failing/non-execution of interdependent tests in Robot Framework

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I have a large number of test cases, in which several test cases are interdependent. Is it possible that while a later test case is getting executed you can find out the status of a previously executed test case?
In my case, the 99th test case depends on the status of some prior test cases and thus, if either the 24th or the 38th fails I would like the 99th test case NOT to get executed at all and thus save me a lot of time.
Kindly, explain with some example if possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Robot is very extensible, and a feature that was introduced in version 2.8.5 makes it easy to write a keyword that will fail if another test has failed. This feature is the ability for a [library to act as a listener](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/811). With this, a library can keep track of the pass/fail status of each test. With that knowledge, you can create a keyword that fails immediately if some other test fails.

The basic idea is, cache the pass/fail status as each test finishes (via the special `_end_test` method). Then, use this value to determine whether to fail immediately or not.

Here's an example of how to use such a keyword:

```
*** Settings ***
Library   /path/to/DependencyLibrary.py

*** Test Cases ***
Example of a failing test
    fail  this test has failed

Example of a dependent test
    [Setup] | Require test case | Example of a failing test
    log | hello, world
```

Here is the library definition:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class DependencyLibrary(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL"

    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self
        self.test_status = {}

    def require_test_case(self, name):
        key = name.lower()
        if (key not in self.test_status):
            BuiltIn().fail("required test case can't be found: '%s'" % name)
            
        if (self.test_status[key] != "PASS"):
            BuiltIn().fail("required test case failed: '%s'" % name)

        return True

    def _end_test(self, name, attrs):
        self.test_status[name.lower()] = attrs["status"]
```

Comment: The above has to be marked answered. This is really helpful.
@Bryan: I have a question on this. Instead of FAIL, I want to mark it as Not Executed. Is that possible?

Comment: @Vimal: no, it is not possible.

Comment: @Vimal, you can only have PASS or FAIL status, but you can turn the test non-critical by using [--critical or --noncritical command line options](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-criticality) and changing tags accordingly when failing the tests. `BuiltIn.fail` used above allows setting tags, but you can also use `set_tags` or `remove_tags` methods.

Comment: @BryanOakley - Awesome solution, I use it in my test's suites.

Comment: RF 3.0 needs the last line changed to `self.test_status[name.lower()] = attrs.status`

Comment: @MarkHu: no it doesn't. This code works as posted. At least, not unless there was a bug specific to version 3.0. I just tested it with robot 3.1.2 and it worked just fine.

Comment: Ok, maybe it was the `name` type change that gave me this error `Calling method '_end_test' failed: TypeError: 'TestCase' object is not subscriptable` until I changed to `self.test_status[str(name).lower()] = attrs.status`

Comment: @MarkHu: you must be doing something wrong, because `attrs` should not be a TestCase object. Maybe you're using Listener API version 3. This example is clearly using version 2.

Comment: _Mea culpa_ : I was using `ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3`

Comment: There is a library now that does the same what @BryanOakley describes in his answer. It can be installed with `pip install robotframework-dependencylibrary`. See the code at https://github.com/mentalisttraceur/robotframework-dependencylibrary

Answer (score 8):

To solve this problem I'm using something like this:

```
Run Keyword if  '${PREV TEST STATUS}'=='PASSED'  myKeyword
```

so maybe this will be usable also for you.

Comment: I am using the same as a Test Setup in my suite. I call a keyword in my test setup which checks if the previous test failed. If it has, it will skip all cases until it reaches a case that has tag marked as independent. I check for this tag in my Test Setup keyword and execute the independent test case. Works brilliantly.