# How to stop Robot Framework test execution if first testcase FAIL?

Tags: robotframework

As shown in below robot file, I have three testcases. I want to stop the test execution, if TESTCASE1 fails. TESTCASE2 should be executed only if TESTCASE1 passes.

```
*** Settings ***

Library         pythonLib


*** Test cases ***

TESTCASE1
    boot device

TESTCASE2
    configure device

TESTCASE3
    restart device
```

Is there any keyword or custom way to do this ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a command line option for this, if you want the behavior that robot should stop running as soon as any test fails. This option is `--exitonfailure`. From the robot framework user guide, in a section titled [Stopping when the first test fails](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#stopping-when-first-test-case-fails):

> If option `--exitonfailure` is used, test execution stops immediately if
>   any critical test fails. Also the remaining tests are marked as
>   failed.

You might also want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25079032/7432) to the question [Automatic failing/non-execution of interdependent tests in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25075706/7432), which shows how to write a keyword to implement dependencies between test cases.

Comment: Perhaps similar to `Fatal Error` builtin keyword.

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple ways to get the job done, each appropriate for different situations.

### --exitonfailure

The command line option `--exitonfailure` aborts the test run after **any** testcase fails, unless it is marked [noncritical](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-criticality).

### Fatal Error

You might only want to abort if exactly `TESTCASE1` fails. The [`Fatal Error`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Fatal%20Error) keyword exist just for this purpose:

```
TESTCASE1
    ${passed}=  Run Keyword And Return Status  boot device
    Run Keyword If  not ${passed}  Fatal Error
```

If this seems clunky to you, you can throw fatal errors [directly from Python/Java](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#stopping-test-execution).

### Suite Setup

These tools will get the job done, and are appropriate in some cases. Although in the asker's case, I observe:

- The first testcase must pass for any other tests to run.
- It runs a keyword called `boot device`.

To me that is not a testcase. That is a setup. If you need a setup to run once before a suite of testcases, you should specify it as a `Suite Setup`.

```
***Settings***
    Suite Setup    boot device
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, tests should not be dependent on each other. But, in some cases, when a test is very big (end-to-end tests for example), you may need to split it to multiple tests.

As an addition to the previous answers, and in case you need to stop all remaining tests in case of failure of one test (that may be usable on end-to-end tests that were spliced to multiple tests), you can add this to the setting section:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Teardown       Run Keyword If Test Failed    Fatal Error
```

- "Test Teardown": Runs after each test.
- "Run Keyword If Test Failed": Runs the the Keyword only if the test failed.
- "Fatal Error": A keywork that fails the whole suite, causing all next tests to fail.

Answer (score -2):

--pause_on_failure, this will stop the execution, whenever script hit the error. Script execution won't be resumed unless you explicitly start.

Comment: `pause_on_failure` Doesn't appear to be a valid flag in the current version (3.1.1) of robot framework. Where did you see this?

Comment: This is customized one actually, It wont work right now.