# How to run nested test cases with Robot Framework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I have a list of tests under a testcase . Is it possible to execute nested test cases with Robot framework . Can someone guide me how to run nested test cases with small example. Please ignore if the way of questioning is silly as i am a learner.

```
Test Suite 
----------
---- Test case   
          Check if unix process 1 is running   - PASS / FAIL
          Check if unix process 2 is running   - PASS / FAIL
          Check if unix process 3 is running   - PASS / FAIL
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You mention wanting to run nested test cases, but your comment seems to imply you want to fail a suite of a test case fails. Since running nested test cases is the default behavior, I'm not sure what you are asking. Does the following question give you an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/q/33319992/7432

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for comment.I have updated my question . Can you please let me know whether my question is clear.

Comment: It's still not clear. In your code, what are you calling a "nested testcase"? Are you referring to "Test case2" and "Test case3"?

Comment: I am referring to Test case 1 ( updated with 1 test only ). My goal is to execute set of tests under a test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes You can. Below is an example

```
*** Settings ***
Library  BuiltIn

*** Test Cases ***
TC01
   Log To Console    1
   Log To Console    2
```

This is it. When You run the test case you will get output on console as below:

1
2

However, This is not a recommended design as it introduction more typing when you want to write same test with different datasets.

The suggested approach is -

You can run something like this as well.

Test Suite

```
***** Test Cases*****
Test Case Name

***** Keywords *****
----------
---- Test Case Name
     Run Keyword And Continue on Failure    Check if unix process 1 is running
     Run Keyword And Continue on Failure    Check if unix process 2 is running
     Run Keyword And Continue on Failure    Check if unix process 3 is running
```

This will Ensure that All Test Are executed. Also it will fail the test case if any one of the test fails.

Comment: thanks for solution. I hope this works for me. Let me try and update

Comment: Your terminology is a bit unclear. In robot framework, a test case isn't a single step, it is a collection of steps. This is an example of multiple steps inside a single test case, not nested test cases.

Answer (score 2):

A way to run repeatative testing steps is to use data driven testing - [a link to the user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates).
Consider this example:

```
*** Test Cases***
Test case
    [Templete]    Check if the unix process is running
    Subtest1    proc1
    Subtest2    proc2

*** Keywords ***
Check if the unix process is running
    [Arguments]   ${process name}
    # the keyword implementation
```

When `Test Case` is ran, `Subtest1` and `Subtest2` will be executed with the corresponding parameter, and they will have separate PASS/FAIL statuses- so if `Subtest1` fails, `Subtest2` will run regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have one test case run a different test case. What you can do instead is create a keyword, and call that keyword from a test case.

In your case, you can create a keyword named "check if unix process is running", and pass it an id or name or something like that. You can run that keyword, and if it fails, you can fail the test without running any more keywords in that test. Any other tests in the same file will still run.

Answer (score 1):

Tanmay's answer is a good one and should suffice for most use cases.

As an alternative, you can also leverage [Run Keyword And Return Status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status) which merely captures the Pass/Fail status of the daughter keyword it executes. I have some large-ish test cases that have many atomic steps that may or may not succeed, and I'd prefer to have a running eval that gets posted to the **Message** column of the report (using the [Set Test Message](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Message) keyword).