# How to re-start execution step from where it failed in Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

Do we have some way to re-execute test from where it got failed? First i had thought to keep step in different test cases and use (--rerunfailed) option, so that I can start re-executing from specific step, But I do not have control to stop execution flow as after failure of current test it will go to next test case.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think i can use (--exitonfailure) option to overcome my limitation, as given in [how-to-stop-robot-framework-test-execution-if-first-testcase-fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319992/how-to-stop-robot-framework-test-execution-if-first-testcase-fail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we have some way to re-execute test from where it got failed?

No, robot does not allow you to do that. The `--rerunfailed` option is the only option you have, and it will re-run an entire test case.