# Run test if all previous have passed

Tags: robotframework

TL:DR;
I want to run a test if all previous tests have passed, otherwise skip on to the next test.

I have a sequence with a couple of tests:

```
Test A, Test B and Test C
```

If all those tests pass I want to run test D. I have found two solutions that wont work in my application.

1. Run robot with `--exitonfailure` to stop at the first failing test. The problem here is that I want to log all tests whether they pass or fail, for future reference and statistics.
2. Put Test D as a keyword and use `Run Keyword If All Tests Passed | Test D` in Suite Teardown. The problem here is that the tests are run inside a GUI where the tests are displayed as they run, Running Test A etc. If I put test D in Suite Teardown it wont be visible if it fails.

Basically I would like a function like `Run Keyword If All Tests Passed | Test D` that works outside teardown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot skip tests once the test suite starts. The best you can do is add a keyword that causes a test to pass or fail depending on the results of another test, and then call that keyword in the test setup.

The ability to skip tests has been discussed for many years, but at the time that I write this there's still a lot of hesitation by the core team to add the feature.

There is currently an open ticket in the robot framework ticket tracking system for this feature, with plenty of discussion. See https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2087

For an implementation of a library that will let you fail a test if a previous test fails, see this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25079032/7432) to the question [Automatic failing/non-execution of interdependent tests in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25075706/7432). It should be a fairly simple modification to get it to pass a test rather than cause it to fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent a time consuming execution of test suite D when it would just slowly fail due to previous failure, just run it as [suite of suites](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id494) with global variable. 
Change the global variable in Suite Teardown of A,B,C [conditionally](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If%20Any%20Tests%20Failed) and call [Fatal Error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Fatal%20Error) in the Suite Setup of test suite D conditionally on the global variable value.

That should prevent the execution and fail all the D from start.

I used similar thing where I had to do e2e test over several things that had to be in separate test suite files. If the initial login failed, it made no sense to continue so I failed the rest like this.