# How to run suite tests with several values as a loop using Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

please someone can help me to how to run suite tests with several values as a loop using Robot framework with Template as follows:

FIRST EXECUTION:

---> Suite Setup: OPEN APP

Add Employee1 :: Verify adding an employee
---> SCENARIO 01

---> first_name: John

---> last_name: Doe

---

---> SCENARIO 02

---> first_name: Monty

---> last_name: Python

---

---> SCENARIO 03

---> first_name: Knight

---> last_name: Ni

---

---> Suite Teardown: CLOSE APP
| PASS |

## -------------------------------------------------------

SECONDE EXECUTION:

---> Suite Setup: OPEN APP

Add Delete Employee :: Verify deleting an employee
---> SCENARIO 01

---> first_name: John

---> last_name: Doe

---

---> SCENARIO 02

---> first_name: Monty

---> last_name: Python

---

---> SCENARIO 03

---> first_name: Knight

---> last_name: Ni

---

---> Suite Teardown: CLOSE APP
| PASS |

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like something you can try doing on the command line. I think you can for loop over your robot execution command perhaps

Comment: I found the solution in the answer of the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65963879/in-robot-framework-how-can-i-execute-multiple-of-test-cases-in-data-driven-meit Thanks for contributing

Answer (score 0):

You can create two lists and then use the value index wise

```
@{firstNameList} create list  John  Monty  Knight
@{LastNameList} create list  Doe Python  Ni

TestCase1
{firstNameList}[1]
{LastNameList}[1]

 TestCase2
{firstNameList}[2]
{LastNameList}[2]
```