# How to execute multiple test cases in one test suite with data driven tests using Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework, data-driven-tests

I have set of Test cases (say 10) which I would like to execute against different URLs (say 50).

I have defined a CSV file containing the 50 URLs
My current solution is using DataDriver Library and adding the CSV file but the problem is that this solution supports only one test case per file, so if I have like 10 test cases then I'll need to create 10 files and any new test case means creating a new file

I have come across this question [In Robot framework, how can I execute multiple of test cases in data driven meithod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65963879/in-robot-framework-how-can-i-execute-multiple-of-test-cases-in-data-driven-meit) and I have read @Bence Kaulics's answer using dynamically generated test cases but my problem in that solution is that I have to put the keyword in a "Suite Setup" however I have another Suite Setup that I want to be executed, Is there any solution that this keyword gets executed in a Test Case or even a Test Setup?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.