# Is there a way to dynamically build a robot framework suite setup with multiple keywords?

Tags: python, robotframework

I am building robot framework suites and tests dynamically for unit testing. We have a `Global Setup` that applies to all tests at the suite level. However, some sets of tests have additional setup that could also be applied at the suite level. Is there any built-in way to append more keywords to the suite setup?

I have something like this:

```py
from robot.api import TestSuite

suite = TestSuite("Foo")
suite.setup.config(name="Global Setup")
# i want to then append to suite.setup based on some condition
if bar:
    # append more keywords to suite.setup
...
# add tests etc
...
result = suite.run(output="out.xml", loglevel="TRACE")
```

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67193693/create-robot-framework-test-case-dynamically-on-running-test-suite/67198255#67198255

Comment: @ClaudioBatista thanks for the reference. I have seen that, but I don't think it applies to dynamically adding to a suite setup.

Comment: Maybe you could use the listener interface `start_suite` method. You should be able to view and modify setup keywords. https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id934

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to ADD more keywords to the suite setup via the listener approach. Below is the best I could muster. Maybe it is obvious, but it also seems like there should be a better way.

I updated `suite.setup.config` to run `Run Keywords` and used an `AND` in the `args` so that I could add multiple keywords to the suite setup.

```py
from robot.api import TestSuite

suite = TestSuite("Foo")
suite.setup.config(name="Global Setup")
# i want to then append to suite.setup based on some condition
if bar:
    # append more keywords to suite.setup
    suite.setup.config(name="Run Keywords", args=["Global Setup", "AND", "Other Setup"...])
...
# add tests etc
...
result = suite.run(output="out.xml", loglevel="TRACE")
```